# Python Beautiful Soup - Removed Tag Still Influencing Output

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

### Hi,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<p>This <i>is</i> a test.</p>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

print(soup)
for tag in soup.find_all('i'):
    tag.replace_with('is')
print(soup)

print("\n")

print(soup.prettify())

print("\n")

for string in soup.stripped_strings:
    print(string)
```

This programs outputs the following:

```
<html><body><p>This <i>is</i> a test.</p></body></html>
<html><body><p>This is a test.</p></body></html>


<html>
 <body>
  <p>
   This
   is
   a test.
  </p>
 </body>
</html>


This
is
a test
```

Why though?
Why is the string still splitted in three parts as if the removed tag was still present?
If I use `<p>This is a test.</p>` (which is the output after I replaced the tag) as my starting html everything is working fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it replace `<i>is</i>` with `is` but it doesn't replace node in tree and it still treads `is` as separated item in tree.

You would have to convert tree to string and parse it again to get it as single node in tree.

```
html = str(soup)
#print(html)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
```

---

If you want text as one string then you can try `get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<p>This <i>is</i> a test.</p>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

print(soup.get_text(strip=True, separator=" "))
```